# Adjusting group header vertically to fit content when content is printed to screen from a field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have content that is pulled from a DB field that is going into my crystal reports into the page header. The issue I am having is the content is sometimes too large to fit into my group header. I need to find a way to have crystal reports adjust the height of the group header because I have multiple group headers that will print in that section. I have "Can Grow" checked on the "format editor" set to unlimited lines, but I also have a few other fields in the group headers that don't give me the option to "can grow". I think I need to do something with a formula but I'm not sure how I can accomplish this. Here is a screen shot of the issue I am talking about. Any help with this would be appreciated thanks. I am using Crystal Reports Version 14.1.8.2060

[image]

Comment: From your screenshot the issue seems more like the horizontal bar not moving below the group header text – as the whole group header is shown, i.e. it's field height is grown as configured. You could try to add another group header section below the existing one, and move the horizontal bar to that new section.

Comment: Works also with a box: One can resize its height so that the lower bar is positioned in the  additional section.

Comment: I actually clicked on the horizontal lines and there was a setting on them to grow with content and that did the trick. You got me on the right track though thank you.